# Create Two Way Local/Unix Socket

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, boost, boost-asio

Is there a way to create a 2 way local/Unix socket using `boost::asio`. My current Operating System (Ubuntu) supports Unix sockets but I can't quite figure out how to create one. The official boost resources don't tell me much but it appears to be the only resource available at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [`boost::asio::local::connect_pair()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/local__connect_pair/overload1.html) free function. It can be used with stream or datagram local sockets.

Comment: But what do I connect?

Comment: The two sockets are connected to each other